# What are the differences between Process.Close() and Process.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, process

I start a `Process` then I want to make sure it will be closed properly. I have used `Process.Close()` to close it but sometime it was still locking the resources. I can see we have `Process.Dispose()` method. I just want to know what are the **actual differences** between them and should I call them both to make sure that process will be closed?

```
p.Dispose();
p.Close();
```

Comment: What do **you** mean by _"process will be closed"_? Calling `Close()` on a process does not **terminate** it.

Comment: Basically, all the `Close` methods in the Framework are a design mistake and should not exist. I think they predate the Dispose/using pattern. Any use of them is a code smell.

Comment: There is no difference.  Applies to about all framework classes that have a Close() method.  Intentional design, you'd rely on Dispose by using the *using* statement, if the object needs to survive beyond the method body (so that the using statement is not useful) then it needs to be explicit and using Close() makes sense.  Whether that's good design is very subjective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [documentation of `Process.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx);

> The `Dispose` method calls `Close`. Placing the `Process` object in a [`using`
>   block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) disposes of resources *without* the need to call `Close`.

That means, there is no difference. Internally, all `Close` methods in .NET calls `Dispose` method as far as I know.

If you look at [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,1298);

```
public void Close()
{
      ...        
      m_processHandle.Close();
      ...
}
```

and this method [calls](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,244);

```
public void Close() {
    Dispose(true);
}
```

You should *always* use `using` statement for a `Process` object. It allows early cleanup of resources so you don't need to wait until they garbage collected.

Answer (score 4):

> Difference between `Close()` and `Dispose()` Method
>
> `Close()` Vs `Dispose()` Method

The basic difference between `Close()` and `Dispose()` is, when a `Close()` method is called, any managed resource can be temporarily closed and can be opened once again. It means that with the same object the resource can be reopened or used. Whereas `Dispose()` method permanently removes any ((un)managed) resource from memory for cleanup and the resource no longer exists for any further processing.

> Example showing difference between `Close()` and `Dispose()` Methods:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Test
{
    private string connString = "Data Source=COMP3;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User Id=sa;Password=pass";
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public Test()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.ConnectionStatus();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void ConnectionStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection opened..");
            }

            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed..");
            }
            // connection.Dispose();

            if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection again opened..");
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message+"\n"+ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch(Exception ey)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ey.Message+"\n"+ey.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection closed and disposed..");
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example if you uncomment the `connection.Dispose()` method and execute, you will get an exception such as

> The `ConnectionString` property has not been initialized.

This is the difference between `Close()` and `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2):

Dispose normally free's the UnManaged resources that are held inside the class. It has no effect on the process itself.

so far to dispose. As taken from the MSDN the Close mehtod does:

> Frees all the resources that are associated with this component.
>   ref: [MSDN Process.Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

So from the outside there is no difference, but lets take a look in the glorious .net SourceCode: [Process](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,f8b2e604d6f1fe04)

```
   /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       Frees any resources associated with this component.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public void Close() {
        if (Associated) {
            if (haveProcessHandle) {
                StopWatchingForExit();
                Debug.WriteLineIf(processTracing.TraceVerbose, "Process - CloseHandle(process) in Close()");
                m_processHandle.Close();
                m_processHandle = null;
                haveProcessHandle = false;
            }
            haveProcessId = false;
            isRemoteMachine = false;
            machineName = ".";
            raisedOnExited = false;

            //Don't call close on the Readers and writers
            //since they might be referenced by somebody else while the 
            //process is still alive but this method called.
            standardOutput = null;
            standardInput = null;
            standardError = null;

            output = null;
            error = null;


            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

while dispose does this

```
    /// <internalonly/>
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       Free any resources associated with this component.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if( !disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                //Dispose managed and unmanaged resources
                Close();
            }
            this.disposed = true;
            base.Dispose(disposing);                
        }            
    }
```

So as you can see, even internally there is no difference. Dispose just wraps the close mehtod.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where MSDN is actually really helpful

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx

notice that if you want to use the "using" construction:

```
using (MyResource myRes = new MyResource())
{
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
```

you need your object to support IDisposable, and:

> The IDisposable interface requires the implementation of a single
>   parameterless method, Dispose.

the Dispose method is also what is called by the garbage colledtor, before removing all references to the object, ensuring that the object is nicely cleaned up..

Hence the implementation of IDisposable, and usage of such, is a way for you to ensure that the resources hugged by an object are freed, before the object is actually removed from memory by garbage collector..

you can enforce this by using `using`

genericly close does not implement this.
but sometimes it does wrap the Dispose method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx

> Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream. Instead of calling this method, ensure that the stream is properly disposed.

for the Process class, it's the other way around.